# Can I import a mysql dump to a laravel migration?

Tags: laravel

I have a complete database and need to create migration. I guess there must be a way to do it from a dump but not sure. Is there any way automatically or at least easier to do this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can dump to a CSV:
An alternative for some generic data tables (Countries, States, Postal Codes), not via migrations but via seeders. Although you could do it the same way in a migration file.

In your seeder file:

```
    public function run()
    {
        $this->insertFromCsvFile('countries', 'path/to/countries.csv');
        $this->insertFromCsvFile('states', 'path/to/states.csv');
        $this->insertFromCsvFile('postal_codes', 'path/to/postal_codes.csv');
    }

    private function insertFromCsvFile($tableName, $filePath)
    {
        if( !file_exists($filePath) ){
            echo 'File Not Found: '.$filePath."\r\n";
            return;
        }
        $headers = $rows = [];
        $file = fopen( $filePath, 'r' );
        while( ( $line = fgetcsv( $file ) ) !== false ){

            // The first row should be header values that match column names.
            if( empty( $headers ) ){
                $headers = explode( ',', implode( ',', $line ) );
                continue;
            }

            $row = array_combine( $headers, $line );
            foreach( $row as &$val ) if( $val === 'NULL' ) $val = null;
            $rows[] = $row;

            // Adjust based on memory constraints.
            if( count($rows) === 500 ){
                DB::table( $tableName )->insert($rows);
                $rows = [];
            }
        }
        fclose( $filePath );

        if( count($rows) ) DB::table( $tableName )->insert($rows);
    }
```

Run the seeder: `php artisan db:seed --class=GenericTableSeeder`

Answer (score 68):

You can import dumps in Laravel like this:

```
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('full/path/to/dump.sql'));
```

If I were to refactor an existing app, though, I'd take the time to write migrations from scratch, import the dump into different tables (or a different db, if table names are the same) then import the content to the new structure via seeds.

Comment: what if the filesize is too large to fit in memory?

Comment: That's a different problem altogether. You can increase the memory limit in your PHP's ini file, or do it programatically on your seeder like this: `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')`

Comment: Yes it's a different problem but still file_get_contents will fail with "too large" files, like many many gigabytes. I would use your approach but with fopen and fgets. phpMyAdmin exports can be chunked with "INSERT INTO"

Answer (score 20):

Laravel can't do that, but I think this will help: [Laravel migration generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator)

It generate migrations based on existing tables.

Comment: This is no longer support for L5

Comment: Update: there is support for [Larabel 5+](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator)

Comment: I have just recently used this schema -> migration converter with great results: https://github.com/aljorhythm/sql-to-laravel-migrations

Answer (score 14):

This question is answered already, but recently in a project, the provided answers did not satisfy my needs any longer. It also does not import a whole database dump, but one (large) table. I felt I should share that with you.

The problem was, I wanted to import a quite large table (list of zipcodes) during my artisan:migrate operation. The solution with DB::unprepared($dump) took way to long and I found an alternative which is **MUCH faster**.

Just export your table as CSV and use the following Code in your migration's up() function.

```
    // i had to str_replace the backslash on windows dev system... but works on linux, too
    $filename = str_replace("\\", "/", storage_path('path/in/storage/to/your/file.csv'));

    $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filename."' INTO TABLE yourtable
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
        ENCLOSED BY ''
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 0 LINES
        (col1,col2,...);";

    DB::unprepared($query);
```

Just update the query as you need. And of course, you should make sure, that the table with the cols
'col1', 'col2' etc... exists. I created it just before the importing of the file. with Schema::create()...

If you run into following error message:

```
PDO::exec(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden
```

There is a way you can get rid of this message: Although it's not really documented you can just add an 'options' key to your config/database.php file. For example mine looks like that:

```
        'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'options'   => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
        )
```

Note: i'm currently using laravel 5 but it should work with laravel 4, too.

Comment: this is probabily the best absolutely way, especially when the database gets huge

Comment: That is a good solution as long as the database server exists on the same machine as the webserver, because `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` will fail otherwise.

Comment: @rahmanisback no, the file path needs to be a path to the file on the databaseserver, no matter where that database is. So if you put your dump in /tmp/dump.sql on a remote database and you call it with that path, it will work.

Comment: @EllertvanKoperen yes exactly but migration scripts are parts of the application code and one should never assume any code files will go to database server. Also Migration, as a term, should be bundled with application code, not uploaded to database server individually in case db server is different than web server. One should code with no initial premise of where database and application are hosted.

Comment: @rahmanisback you are right about what one should assume and not assume. However the remote restore does work, and in some cases is a very important timesaver.

Answer (score 12):

> I have a complete database and need to create migration. I guess there must be a way to do it from a dump but not sure. Is there any way automatically or at least easier to do this task?

Not automatically, but we run dumps in a migration using `DB::unprepared()`. You could use `file_get_contents` to import from a `.sql` file and thus not have to worry about escaping the entire dump's `"` marks...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ImportDump extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared("YOUR SQL DUMP HERE");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: This solution works for database with multiple character sets and collations MySQL database.

Comment: I had to use DB::unprepared() when using a sql file exportet with phpmyadmin, as DB::statement()  throws sql syntax error . See tbuteler 's answer

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Neat, I didn't know that existed. Revised the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative is using the PDO directly:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$sql_dump = File::get('/path/to/file.sql');
DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql_dump);
```

Comment: It will be pretty useful to specify what specific `File` class you suggest to use.

Comment: When using this option, you can use the file_get_contents function to get the sql dump. Also ensure you do not use LOCK TABLES, otherwise you will get an error when Laravel writes into the migrations table

Answer (score 10):

I am writing my answer as this might help to someone who is using new laravel 8.

In laravel 8, dumping SQL and run migration using SQL(.dump) file is possible. Please refer below link for more detail.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#squashing-migrations

```
php artisan schema:dump

// Dump the current database schema and prune all existing migrations...
php artisan schema:dump --prune
```

`schema:dump` will create new directory under database > schema and SQL dump will stored there.
After that when you try to migrate first it will run dump file from schema and then any pending migration.

Comment: 7 years after my original question. Laravel 8 do the right with schema:dump

Comment: Additionally, "Now, when you attempt to migrate your database and no other migrations have been executed, Laravel will first execute the SQL statements in the schema file of the database connection you are using." https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#squashing-migrations

Comment: Just a note that this is only for the schema and not actual data

Answer (score 6):

another solution work for me in Laravel 5.2:

`DB::unprepared(File::get('full/path/to/dump.sql'));`

Comment: Interesting and elegant approach that should work but isn't in my case. Would be interesting to know more.

Comment: If you use a dump from phpmyadmin, it often include option like following : ```SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";```
Get rid of it, and it's going to work

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution provided by Laravel Article for generating migration file from an existing database table.

Try: https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-migration-generator-online
[image]

Comment: the question was completely something else!

Comment: Yes its off topic but thats exactly what i needed... importing an existing schema into a migration.

Comment: If anybody else has an issue with converting with this page - remove extra spaces after the table name 

Answer (score 2):

You can create laravel migration and models directly from database using https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator

Execute the following code after installing the package

```
php artisan larry:fromdb
```

Answer (score 2):

i recently standing in front of the same problem. i didn't want to install a package specially for that, so i decided to write a little tool to help me and others ;)

Here is the link: 
http://laravel.stonelab.ch/sql-seeder-converter/

And here you can comment it, if you have any improvement proposals or questions: 
http://www.stonelab.ch/en/sql-to-laravel-seeder-converter/

Comment: i detected that in output the commas were missing, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Raahul/Larryfour Package, A model and migration generator for Laravel 4

[Raahul/Larryfour Package](https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator.git)

After insallation you can use a command line to create a migration from existed database like this:

```
php artisan raahul:fromdb --only yourdatabase
```

And you will find the migration in app/migrations/ folder