# Import mysql database/dump into laravel 5.2 migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, dbmigrate

I have a complete mysql database that I need to shift to laravel's database. How can I do that ?

I have so far created a migration for the database - Into this db I want to put data, which is huge. 
I'm not using homestead env. I'm using artisan serve for locally running the application.

I have referenced: [Can I import a mysql dump to a laravel migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307464/can-i-import-a-mysql-dump-to-a-laravel-migration)

I have referenced this link and it did not solve my problem, data did not migrate. I need help to migrate data into the DB created.

tried using:- `DB::unprepared(File::get('full/path/to/dump.sql'));` 
din work out.

Comment: Do you get an error or something when you execute this?

Comment: @TheFallen no error as such. when I executed DB::unprepared(File::get('full/path/to/dump.sql')); in tinker, it just returned false.